# Using DataAdapter in Visual C# with .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataadapter

I have been trying to connect my ms sql database with a .net page using c# however I am encountering a problem and as I am new I am not able to handle the exception that I am getting and wherever I read, I am just not able to understand.
following this will be the code that I am trying to execute, followed by the error and then followed by the desired result.

*CODE:*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection objcon = new SqlConnection();
    objcon.ConnectionString = new System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Master Connection String").ConnectionString;
    objcon.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter objadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    objadapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
    objadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select * from info";
    objadapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objcon;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    objadapter.Fill(ds);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++ )
    {
        Response.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].Values);
    }
```

*ERROR:*
1- 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings' is       a 'property' but is used like a 'type'.

2- 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Values' and no extension method 'Values' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

*DESIRED O/P:*
This was a simple experiment to read the rows of a table and display the entire table on the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
objcon.ConnectionString = new System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```

Use the Brackets instead of parenthesis. You need to put the connectionstring 'Name' in the brackets which is in the web.config file.

```
 <add name="MasterConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MyPC\Sql2008..../>
```

If you still don't understand, let me know in comments.

```
DataTable tbl = ds.Tables[0]
```

or directly in the foreach use the ds.Tables[0].Rows. Though I haven't tested the code, but copying table into another is I think like 'ds.Tables[0].Copy' or something like that. You can look it up.

```
foreach (DataRow item in tbl.Rows)
{
    string var = item["ColumnName"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining the error in detail (and also the second error).

Comment: changed the parenthesis to brackets, still not working and also the foreach is also not working. says tbl doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to put the name of the connectionstring in those brackets. Also, use Dataset instead of tbl as you don't have a tbl/table, rather you are using the dataset. So use that.